# cohomology of complement of smooth ample divisor D in smooth projective variety X

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology

Let X be a smooth projective variety, D a smooth ample divisor. Let $X \setminus D=U$ be the affine variety. When is the map $H^*(X) \to H^*(U)$ trivial when $* \neq 0$? I can see that the Lefschetz hyperplane theorem gives me a lot of information about this, but it seems like there should be a very explicit condition about the pair (X,D).